# Getting myBB threads from a specific forum and display them on another page?

Tags: php, mybb

Hello I am trying to display up to 5 threads on my homepage from a specific forum. So I want to get the threads from 'Announcments' located in http://example.com/forum and display them on the homepage in a list.

How can I do this using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to get an RSS feed from MyBB: http://wiki.mybb.com/index.php/RSS_Syndication.  Looks like you can set the limit to 5 threads and select a forum to syndicate.

Then it's a matter of parsing your RSS feed using PHP.  Half-baked code to get you started:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

$items = $xml->channel->item;

foreach($items as $item) {
  $title = $item->title;
  $link = $item->link;
  $pubDate = $item->pubDate;
  $description = $item->description;

  // echo and format variables

  }
```

Comment: It's possible to do it with a database query, it'll be a lot faster but your answer is a nice quick-n-dirty solution